# How to get the reference to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, pass-by-reference, jsonpath

Given my JSON

```
countries: [
     {country: "canada",
      capital: "ottawa",
      territories: [
          yukon: {
               capital: "yellowknife",
               ...
          }
          ...
      ]
      ...
     }
 ]
```

How can I get a reference to the `yukon` object for instance?

I want to have something like

```
yukon = countries[0].territories[0]
```

and then make edits to `yukon` that will reflect in the original JSON. For example,

```
yukon.size = 1123300;
```

Comment: Your syntax is broken. Territories is an array and must contain elements, not property value pairs.

Answer (score -1):

You are already half the way

```
var yukon = countries[0].territories[0].yukon;

yukon.size = 1123300;
```

Comment: Before posting an answer, you should check it by running it somewhere. This wouldn't have run, because the original data object is malformed--it can't decide if it wants `territories` to be an array or an object. How can you suggest to someone how to access a property inside an object when the object is not even formed correctly?